Install gdal2tiles.py with gdal 3.10 from source
I tried to install gdal2tiles.py together with the GDAL version 3.10. I checked out the code for GDAL from GitHub and switched to the release/3.10 branch. Everything worked as it should. GDAL is installed in /usr/local.
gdalinfo --version gives me GDAL 3.10.0, released 2024/11/10.
When I try to install (see) gdal2tiles.py via pip or also from sources, I fail.
The installation process with pip interrupts with the error message:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygdal==3.10.0.dev0 (from gdal2tiles) (from versions: 1.8.1.0, 1.8.1.1, 1.8.1.2,..., 3.7.0.11, 3.7.0.12, 3.7.1.11, 3.7.1.12, 3.7.2.11, 3.7.2.12)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pygdal==3.10.0.dev0 (from gdal2tiles)

To checkout the master branch of gdal2tiles.py and install it from git does also not work. I get the following error message:
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gdal2tiles-0.1.9-py3.8.egg
Processing dependencies for gdal2tiles==0.1.9
Searching for pygdal==3.10.0.dev0
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/pygdal/
No local packages or working download links found for pygdal==3.10.0.dev0
error: Could not find a suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pygdal==3.10.0.dev0')

So, it seems that gdal2tiles needs pygdal as a dependency, which makes sense because it is a python script. However, I am not able to find a newer pygdal version than 3.7.2.
How do I install a current version of gdal2tiles.py with (py)gdal newer than 3.7.2? Or, how can I use gdal2tiles.py with (py)gdal 3.10?

gdal comes with gdal2tiles.py. Do you really need to use this fork?

I noticed, that gdal2tiles is shipped with gdal now, which I was not aware before. I am writing an answer currently with this information and what else I needed to get it to work. Thank you.

The main issue for me was, that cmake was not able to find the swig executable, which is needed to generate the bindings for other programming languages like python. Without swig available, the python bindings were not generated and installed and gdal2tiles was not able to find pygdal.
Another issue was, that I had to set the install path to /usr. Otherwise the gdal tools were not able to find the libgdal library.
In the following, I will explain in a bit more detail to show, how I got it to run.

Install gdal with gdal2tiles from source
I was able to install gdal2tiles with gdal 3.10. I did the following steps:

Clone gdal from github
Switch to branch of desired release (3.10 for me): git switch release/3.10
Install developmend dependencies and swig:

sudo apt install -y libjson-c-dev libxml2-dev libzstd-dev liblzma-dev libgeos-dev libarmadillo-dev libproj-dev libqhull-dev libxerces-c-dev libtiff-dev libgeotiff-dev libpoppler-dev libgif-dev libcfitsio-dev libwebp-dev libopenjp2-7-dev libkml-dev libfyba-dev libpcre3-dev libspatialite-dev libfreexl-dev libogdi-dev swig


Let cmake build and install gdal:
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DSWIG_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/swig4.0 ..
sudo cmake --build . --target install




I had to set the install path to /usr, otherwise the gdal-tool were not able to find the libgdal.so.
I also had to set the swig executable by SWIG_EXECUTABLE, because cmake was not able to find the systems swig executable.


Uninstall gdal
If you want to uninstall gdal and gdal2tiles from your machine use these commands:

run from build directory: sudo make uninstall

